# Error: Cannot create instance of X; no code at address

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, truffle-migration, ganache

Having a little issue. I have deployed a Mock ERC20 contract on development network like so:

```
const ERC20Mock = artifacts.require("ERC20Mock");

module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    if (network === "development") {
        console.log("Deploying MockDAI on Development at: ", accounts[5]);
        await deployer.deploy(ERC20Mock, accounts[5], 100*(10**6), {from: accounts[5]});
    }
}
```

And trying to interact with `truffle test`:

```
contract("Erc20Teller", function([_, adminRole, user ]) {
  let daiAddress;
  beforeEach(async function() {
    daiAddress = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[5];
    this.daiToken = await ERC20Mock.at(daiAddress);
  });
```

However, I am receiving  `Error: Cannot create instance of ERC20Mock; no code at address 0x7F39C89Ed1954AB82361C23f6c02b420DF65b3D0` even though the same address is clearly being used in my migrations and in the unit test. What could the problem be?

Comment: The fact that you're deploying your contract using account `0x7F39C89Ed1954AB82361C23f6c02b420DF65b3D0` doesn't mean that your contract will be deployed to this address. In fact, it will NOT be deployed to this address, hence the error.

Comment: @goodvibration, I see! How would I find where the contract is deployed to?

Comment: Side note: The second argument to Truffle's `contract` function is an array of all available accounts. So you may start your test with `contract("Erc20Teller", function(accounts) {`, and then simply use `accounts[5]` instead of `(await web3.eth.getAccounts())[5]`.

Comment: I don't rely on Truffle migration infrastructure, so I'm not quite sure. But you can simply mask your migration altogether, for example, by changing `if (network === "development")` to `if (network === "production")`, and then deploy the contract in your test instead, via `this.daiToken = await artifacts.require("ERC20Mock").new();`.